# Problems subsetting columns based on values from two separate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mapply

I am using data obtained from a spatially gridded system, for example a city divided up into equally spaced squares (e.g. 250m2 cells). Each cell possesses a unique column and row number with corresponding numerical information about the area contained within this 250m2 square (say temperature for each cell across an entire city). Within the entire gridded section (or the example city), I have various study sites and I know where they are located (i.e. which cell row and column each site is located within). I have a dataframe containing information on all cells within the city, but I want to subset this to only contain information from the cells where my study sites are located. I previously asked a question on this '[Matching information from different dataframes and filtering out redundant columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214763/matching-information-from-different-dataframes-and-filtering-out-redundant-colum)'. Here is some example code again:

```
###Dataframe showing cell values for my own study sites
Site <- as.data.frame(c("Site.A","Site.B","Site.C"))
Row <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3))
Column <- as.data.frame(c(5,4,3))
df1 <- cbind(Site,Row, Column)
colnames(df1) <- c("Site","Row","Column")

###Dataframe showing information from ALL cells
eg1 <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(5,4,3,2,1)) ##Cell rows and columns
eg2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:50, 15*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)) ##Numerical information
df2 <- rbind(eg1,eg2)
rownames(df2)[1:2] <- c("Row","Column")
```

From this, I used the answer from the previous questions which worked perfectly for the example data.

```
output <- df2[, (df2['Row', ] %in% df1$Row) & (df2['Column', ] %in% df1$Column)]
names(output) <- df1$Site[mapply(function(r, c){which(r == df1$Row & c == df1$Column)}, output[1,], output[2,])]
```

However, I cannot apply this to my own data and cannot figure out why.

EDIT: Initially, I thought there was a problem with naming the columns (i.e. the 'names' function). But it would appear there may be an issue with the 'output'  line of code, whereby columns are being included from df2 that shouldn't be (i.e. the output contained columns from df2 which possessed column and row numbers not specified within df1).

I have also tried:

```
output <- df2[, (df2['Row', ] == df1$Row) & (df2['Column', ] == df1$Column)]
```

But when using my own (seemingly comparable) data, I don't get information from all cells specified in the 'df1' equivalent (although again works fine in the example data above). I can get my own data to work if I do each study site individually.

```
SiteA <- df2[, which(df2['Row', ] == 1) & (df2['Column', ] == 5)]
SiteB <- df2[, which(df2['Row', ] == 2) & (df2['Column', ] == 4)]
SiteC <- df2[, which(df2['Row', ] == 3) & (df2['Column', ] == 3)]
```

But I have 1000s of sites and was hoping for a more succinct way. I am sure that I have maintained the same structure, double checked spellings and variable names. Would anyone be able to shed any light on potential things which I could be doing wrong? Or failing this an alternative method?

Apologies for not providing an example code for the actual problem (I wish I could pinpoint what the specific problem is, but until then the original example is the best I can do)! Thank you.

Comment: All I can say for the moment is that `names()` expects a character vector with as many elements inside as `output`has columns. If that is not the case, this line will throw an error. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html

Comment: You may want to wrap `mapply` around `unlist` because it returns a `list` and you want a `vector`: ```output <- df2[, (df2['Row', ] %in% df1$Row) & (df2['Column', ] %in% df1$Column)]; 
names(output) <- df1$Site[unlist(mapply(function(r, c){which(r == df1$Row & c == df1$Column)}, output[1,], output[2,]))]```.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. However, I have tried adding duplicate columns to 'df2' (which may be a problem with my own data) but the code still runs fine in the example. And I tried unlisting but this did not assign the appropriate column names to the corresponding cell value specified in the 'df1' equivalent for my own data (although again seems to work in the example above).

Comment: Can you please tweak the data to provide a case where the example above would not work? Also, would you mind sharing what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: The problem may be when creating 'output', rather than the 'names' function. I will edit the question accordingly but I still don't know why this isn't working. 

df1 contains column and row values for grid cells where my sites are located. df2 contains information for lots more grid cells, with the first 2 rows of this dataframe (see eg1) showing the cell information for grid cells (i.e. rows and columns). I want to subset df2 so it only provides information for the cells of interest (i.e. with row and column numbers outlined in df1). I am not achieving this with my own data.

Comment: "I cannot see why the code does not hold" -- Try running pieces of the code to see if they align with your expectations instead of convincing yourself from what you think are first principles. Seems pretty obvious from the error message that you needed to inspect whether `mapply` was giving you a list here...

Comment: I am still beyond confused as to what you're trying to get. Also, why are you using `rownames` here and only supplying it with two elements when your dataframe is more than 2 rows? Anytime you index with `Row` and `Column`, you're only looking at the first two rows.

Comment: My apologies and thank you for your perseverance in trying to help me! In the example I have 2 dataframes, I want to subset columns in df2 based on what values are in the first 2 rows of this dataframe. I want to keep columns based on what values are in the first 2 columns in df1. 

The 'output' in the example is exactly what I need, it only keeps columns in df2 who's values in the first 2 rows match up with columns 2 and 3 in df1. But this is not what I get when I use my actual data and I am struggling to figure out why. Is this any clearer sorry?

Comment: @JamesWhite, I have just added some edits to my answer. I am still not convinced that I fully understand your question, but let me know if the edits aren't helpful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only apparent issue I can see is that `mapply` is not wrapped around `unlist`. `mapply` returns a `list`, which is not what you're after for subsetting purposes. So, try:

```
output <- df2[, (df2['Row', ] %in% df1$Row) & (df2['Column', ] %in% df1$Column)]
names(output) <- df1$Site[unlist(mapply(function(r, c){which(r == df1$Row & c == df1$Column)}, output[1,], output[2,]))]
```

Edit:

If the goal is to grab columns whose first 2 rows match the 2nd and 3rd elements of a given row in `df1`, you can try the following:

```
output_df <- Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), data.frame(do.call(cbind,apply(df2, 2, function(x) {
  ##Create a condition vector for an if-statement or for subsetting
  condition <- paste0(x[1:2], collapse = "") == apply(df1[,c('Row','Column')], 1, function(y) {
    paste0(y,collapse = "")
  })
  ##Return a column if it meets the condition (first 2 rows are matched in df1)
  if(sum(condition) != 0) {
    tempdf <- data.frame(x)
    names(tempdf) <- df1[condition,]$Site[1]
    tempdf
  } else {
    ##If they are not matched, then return an empty column
    data.frame(rep(NA,nrow(df2)))
  }
}))))
```

It is quite a condensed piece of code, so I hope the following explanation will help clarify some things:

This basically goes through every column in `df2` (with `apply(df2, 2, FUN)`) and checks if its first 2 rows can be found in the 2nd and 3rd elements of every row in `df1`. If the condition is met, then it returns that column in a data.frame format with its column name being the value of `Site` in the matching row in `df1`; otherwise an empty column (with `NA`'s) is returned. These columns are then bound together with `do.call` and `cbind`, and then coerced into a data.frame. Finally, we use the `Filter` function to remove columns whose values are `NA`'s.

All that should give the following:

```
Site.A Site.B Site.C
  1      2      3    
  5      4      3    
 40     42     33    
 13     47     25    
 23      0     34    
  2     41     17    
 10     29     38    
 43     27      8    
 31      1     25    
 31     40     31    
 34     12     43    
 43     30     46    
 46     49     25    
 45      7     17    
  2     13     38    
 28     12     12    
 16     19     15    
 39     28     30    
 41     24     30    
 10     20     42    
 11      4      8    
 33     40     41    
 34     26     48    
  2     29     13    
 38      0     27    
 38     34     13    
 30     29     28    
 47      2     49    
 22     10     49    
 45     37     30    
 29     31      4    
 25     24     31
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly on both the example and my own data and was indeed exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh great! I'm glad that helped.